# How to implement Entity Framework if my tables have unconventional column names?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I've joined a team that uses non standard names for tables and columns, and have trouble building database-first projects with Entity Framework.

Here's my problem:

```
tFWAClientProcessing (Table)
FWAClientHandling (Primary Key, INT)
iClientID (Foreign Key, INT)
```

.

```
tClients (Table)
AClientID (Primary Key, INT)
sClientName (VARCHAR(255))
```

I need Entity Framework to detect the relationship between these two tables without making changes to those tables in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd long given up on EDMX and convention-based mapping for relationships and just set up EF via `EntityConfiguration` classes.  Attributes in the entity definitions are another option which should work for simple cases like identifying column names. You can also wire up mapping in the OnModelCreating override directly.

For instance: To have entities called Client and FWAClientProcessing for that table structure:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
}

public class FWAClientProcessing
{
    public int FWAClientProcessingId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class ClientConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("tClients"); // assumes default schema, i.e. "dbo" in SQL Server. Can add schema name as 2nd parameter otherwise.
        HasKey(x => x.ClientId)
            .Property(x => x.ClientId)
            .HasColumnName("iClientID");
       
        Property(x => x.ClientName)
            .HasColumnName("sClientName");
    }
}

public class FWAClientProcessingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FWAClientPrcessing>
{
    public FWAClientProcessingConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("tFWAClientProcessing"); 
        HasKey(x => x.FWAClientProcessingId)
            .Property(x => x.FWAClientProcessingId)
            .HasColumnName("FWAClientHandling");
       
        HasRequired(x => x.Client)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("iClientID"));
    }
}
```

Assuming that the EntityTypeConfiguration classes are in the same assembly as the entities, and the DBContext, registering them in the context becomes:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
                modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(TypeOf(YourDbContex).Assembly);


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

These examples are for EF6, EF Core uses the concept of Shadow Properties for mapping FK relationships without exposing FK properties, and can accommodate the different column naming. EntityTypeConfiguration is available as an Interface with a `Configure` method accepting the builder.

I favor using the explicit entity type configuration by default as it keeps the configuration nicely isolated and out of the way and can handle all mapping scenarios that might come up that annotations cannot do. It's a bit of a one-off cost to set up, but at least then you have full visibility and control over how the schema is mapped and not simply hoping EF works things out. :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you Steve. I'll start looking into this right away.

Comment: It looks like ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly is an EF Core method. Can you recommend a EF6 equivalent?

Comment: Ah, so it was. I thought I'd taken that from an EF6 project, my bad. I corrected the example. In EF6 it is `AddFromAssembly()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the modern replacement for EDMX-based Database-First and reverse-engineer a code-first model from the existing database.  Customizing an EDMX-based model with its mappings is a rabbit-hole of obsolete technology.

This is available for [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) and [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database#:%7E:text=%20Code%20First%20to%20an%20Existing%20Database%20,a%20model%20it%E2%80%99s%20time%20to%20use...%20More%20).

The reverse-engineered model is then a starting point for you to make model customizations, like mapping the tables and columns to sensible names, and configuring any Navigation Properties that for whatever reason didn't get picked up by the tooling.

Comment: This is great -- thank you very much for responding

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is easier if people follow the entity framework conventions. However, if you have to deviate from them, `OnModelCreating` is your friend.

In `OnModelCreating`, from every Table, column, relation between tables, that are not standard, you can inform entity framework about these deviations.

- You can give different table names
- You can use other column names
- You can say that certain properties should be saved in certain database formats, for instance `ProductPrice` is a decimal with 2 digits after the decimal point, instead of the default number of digits.
- etc.

There seems to be a one-to-many relation between Clients and ClientsProcessing: every Client with primary key Id, has zero or more ClientsProcessings, every ClientProcessing belongs to exactly one Client, namely the Client that the foreign key ClientId refers to.

You want to use unconventional table names, unconventional names for you primary and foreign keys, and you need to inform about what keys are used to define the one-to-many relation.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // Configure DbSet<Client>:
    ver clients = modelBuilder.Entity<Client>();
    clients.ToTable("tClients")
           .HasKey(client => client.Id)

    // property Id should be in "AClientID"
    clients.Property(client => client.Id).HasColumnName("AClientID");
    clients.Property(client => client.Name).HasColumnName("sClientName");
```

Apart from different names of the columns, you can also declare whether the properties are required or optional, what format they should have (is a decimal with two digits after the decimal point, or does it have four digits?), etc.

Do something similar for `modelBuilder.Entity<ClientProcessing>();`

For the one-to-many relation: every Client has zero or more ClientProcessings; every ClientProcessing belongs to exactly one (required!) Client, namely the foreign key that ClientId refers to:

```
clients.HasMany(client => client.ClientProcessings)
       .WithRequired(clientProcessing => clientProcessing.Client)
       .HasForeignKey(clientProcessing => clientProcessing.ClientId);
```

Or if you want, you can start at ClienProcessing: every ClientProcessing has exactly one Client (required!), using foreign key ClientId. Every Client has many ClientProcessings.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClientProcessing>()
            .HasRequired(clientProcessing => clientProcessing.Client)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(clientProcessing => clientProcessing.ClientId);
```

Note: by default this will cascade on delete: whenever you delete a client, you will also delete all its processings: you did define there are no processings without a client.

In some relations, you don't want this, especially many-to-many relations or one-to-zero-or-one relation: a Student may have zero or one School-supplied-Laptop. If you delete the Laptop, you don't want to delete the Student as well. In that case you'll have to add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the useful info. I'm going to start implementing this.